# How to Access item in a Nested Map in a Map (Java)

Tags: java, string, dictionary, hashmap

**Edit**: I've tried the suggested print, but it is giving me syntax errors. Cannot resolve .get Anyone know of a fix?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieaZh.jpg

**Problem**: I have this Java map `Map<String, Object> TestMap = new HashMap<String, Object>()`. 
Inside its object value is another map `Map<String, Integer> NestedTestMap`.

I have `String song` stored as the first map's string key, and I have the second map stored as `String song`'s object value. In the second map, I have `String Championships` stored as its string key, and `Integer 113` stored as its object value.

**Question**: How do I access the integer? I will have to somehow access the first map's string to get to the second map, and get that second map's string's integer. Yeah pretty complicated lol.

**Bonus**: How would I do this as an assert statement? This isnt working for me: `assert (Map<String, Object>)(TestMap.get("song")).get(("Championships").equals(113))`

When I do *not* have nested maps, something like this works fine for me: 
`assert ParsedMap.get("song").equals("kanye")`

Answer (score 5):

Start by defining your Map in a type-safe fashion - it's a `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>`. Unless you've got a good reason it's best not to use a map which returns an Object - it's very difficult to maintain type safety after that.

Once the compiler knows your types it's easy.

```
final Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> myMap = somethingReturningAMap();
assertThat(myMap.get("myName").get("mySong"), equalTo(113));
```

Note: using JUnit/Hamcrest for `assertThat` and `equalTo`.